# Decreasing row length in css and html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to decrease row length of my table, but with height property it is not showing any difference with height. 
 [image: Screenshot of my web page]

My HTML code is

```
     <table id="ProjectTable">  
       <tr> <td>mco1</td>
       ...........
        </tr>
```

What i have tried in css

```
#projectTable tr {
   border:none;
 padding-bottom:6px;
 height:5px;
   }
```

But this is actually not working.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like there last column with the button has equal padding around it. Can you look at that or edit your question to show the css? If you reduced that padding you will see the whole row become "shorter"

Comment: `td` cannot be smaller than their content. `tr` cannot be smaller than all contained `td`.

Comment: does your td's have spesific height or your table?

Comment: @Daniel, for the edit button it taking default padding properties like element.style {
    float: none;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}   So how can i remove that

Comment: @BoraAlpArat, No i did not specify any height to td's.

Comment: You can override this by using "!important" in your own rule for each property. So "padding:5px!important;" should override the in-line style

Comment: @Daniel,Yes it is working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the font size and also the line height:

```
font-size: 8px;
line-height: 8px;
```

Comment: It reduces font-size but not row space.